# Youtube URL getting truncated when I run firefox from terminal

Tags: python, linux, google-chrome, firefox, youtube

I'm running the following command on my terminal:

`firefox https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TbvhGcf6UJU&feature=youtu.be&t=06m56s`

However, when I run that, the time frame part gets truncated and `firefox` opens at this link: `firefox https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TbvhGcf6UJU`

This seems to happen for all videos that contain a time frame. Also this is the message that my terminal gives me:

```
g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
1429336854750   addons.xpi  WARN    Exception running bootstrap method shutdown on webapps-team@lists.launchpad.net: ReferenceError: sss is not defined (resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> file:///usr/share/mozilla/extensions/%7Bec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384%7D/webapps-team@lists.launchpad.net/bootstrap.js:72:4) JS Stack trace: shutdown@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> file:///usr/share/mozilla/extensions/%7Bec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384%7D/webapps-team@bootstrap.js:72:5 < XPI_callBootstrapMethod@XPIProvider.jsm:4305:9 < shutdownObserver@XPIProvider.jsm:1991:13
```

How do I make `firefox` open in the timeframe that is specified in the URL? Any leads appreciated.

I will eventually have to run this using `python3`, in a `os.system` call.

EDIT: I just checked this with `google-chrome` as well, and chrome seems to truncate the url as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have special characters in your url. You have to quote or escape them.

Try this:

```
firefox 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TbvhGcf6UJU&feature=youtu.be&t=06m56s'
```

Comment: Yes, that works! Thank you. 
I'll accept that as the right answer as soon as Stack Overflow allows me to.